# Forloop on a json objects in template issue

Tags: django, python-3.x

I would like to render each row of a pandas DataFrame on my web app, so I convert it to a json object but my queries aren't displayed on my web page. I do not understand why.
Can you help me on this?

view.py

```
def typeDetail(request,id,rt_id):

    normal_price=request.POST.get('normal_price')
    number_of_allotments=request.POST.get('number_of_allotments')

    property=get_object_or_404(Property,id=id)
    roomtype=get_object_or_404(RoomType,id=rt_id)

    dayList=Inventory.objects.filter(
        room_type=rt_id,
        date__gte= datetime.date.today()
    ).order_by('date')

    pd_frame=pd.DataFrame(list(dayList.values()))
    pd_frame['occupancy']=(int(number_of_allotments)-pd_frame['allotment'])/int(number_of_allotments)
    trueList=pd_frame.to_json(orient='records')


    # for day in dayList:
    #     dateList.append(day.date)
    #     price.append(day.pricing)
    #     availability.append(day.allotment)



    return render(request,'livedb_model/typeDetail.html',{
        'property':property,
        'roomtype':roomtype,
        # 'availability':json.dumps(availability),
        # 'price':json.dumps(price),
        # 'dateList':json.dumps(dateList,default=myconverter),
        'trueList':trueList
        })
```

typeDetail.py

```
<ul>
    {% for day in trueList %}
        {% if day.availability.room %}
            <li>{{day.date}}:{{day.allotment}}:{{day.pricing.room.actual_rate.amount}}:{{day.occupancy}} </li>
        {% else %}
            <li>{{day.date}}:0:{{day.pricing.room.actual_rate.amount}} </li>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: what is output of **trueList**

Comment: the output is a list

Comment: if you haven't already, use an IDE with a debugger so you can set a breakpoint and inspect your variables. Don't ask us to debug your code if you haven't tried to debug yourself. Show us `trueList`.

Comment: I tried but I'm facing an other issue : when I'm starting the debugger it stops at the **from .models import Property** telling me that 'attempted relative import with no known parent package' because I'm running the debugger in this particular file.

Comment: You should not be converting your frame to JSON. Send it to the template as a list.